# How many moves is it possible to win in?

Tags: winning

I was wondering what is the minimum number of moves it takes to win (checkmate) as I would like to accomplish this in a game of chess.

Comment: Black can win in 2 moves, if white plays badly enough: 1.f3? e5 2.g4?? Qh4# (the fool's mate). But if your opponent dislikes to cooperate there is no telling how many moves it takes to win.

Comment: maybe if your opponent and you both play "perfectly" the minimum number of moves could be infinite

Comment: @TheAutomaton Actually, since there are only a finite number of states the game can be in, and a state can only be visited 3 times before the game ends there is a maximum game length. That length is estimated to be about 11800 moves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's very, very, very dependent on your opponent. There really is no number you can give for a definite way to get a "auto-checkmate" (if that's what you're looking for) as every opponent has different preferences and playing style. Like @Scounged stated, black can win in two moves. For white, the technical fastest way to win is in three moves (here's one variation: 1. e4 f6 2. Bc4 g5 3. Qh5#) but again, your opponet probably isn't that bad. A very popular fast checkmate against beginners is known as "Scholar's Mate" or more commonly known as the "Four Move Checkmate". It goes something like this: (1. e4 e5 2. Bc4 Bc5 3. Qh5 Nf6 4. Qxf7#).

Now of course, every chess game is uniqiue to it's own. There is no definite number of turns it takes to get a checkmate. On average, they say that it is 40 moves.

If you would like to practice recognizing checkmate patterns and opportunities, I would suggest going to Chess.com or Chessable.com as they have quite a wide variety of material to improve your chess skills.

Comment: I know it's a bit late but thanks for the help.